# trying to send a POST request using python with a JSON object and print the response into a CSV file

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, http, fastify

I am trying to send a post request using python script and want to store the response. Below are the two file. Everything is fine when i do the same thing using node.js but when I use a python script instead of node.js it give me this error. Any one know why? not able to find the proper reason why this error pop up.

in request sending first name and last name and in response i will get the full name

Node.js Code (used fastify)

```js
const conn=require('fastify')({
    logger:true
})
const PORT=80
const axios = require('axios')

//take first and last name as request and in response return full name
conn.post('/user',async(req,res)=>{
    const user=req.body
    const fullname=user.first_name + user.last_name
    console.log(full)
    res.json(fullname)
})


const start_server=async()=>{
    try
    {
        await conn.listen(PORT)
        console.log(`server start at PORT ${PORT}`)
    }
    catch(error)
    {
        conn.log.error(error)
        process.exit(1)
    }
}
start_server()
```

my Python script

```js
import requests
import json
API_ENDPOINT = 'http://localhost:80/user'

headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}

data = {
  "first_name": "jayanta",
  "last_name": "lahkar"
}

r = requests.post('http://localhost:80/user', data)

print(r.json())
```

Error message

```
{'statusCode': 415, 'code': 'FST_ERR_CTP_INVALID_MEDIA_TYPE', 'error': 'Unsupported Media Type', 'message': 'Unsupported Media Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
```

Comment: You define headers in your python script but don't use it in your request

Comment: if i used headers the it give me the below error:   {'statusCode': 400, 'error': 'Bad Request', 'message': 'Unexpected token i in JSON at position 1'}

Comment: You are note actually passing the headers to the function call.

Comment: if i pass header to function call then error will be :  {'statusCode': 400, 'error': 'Bad Request', 'message': 'Unexpected token i in JSON at position 1'}

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
r = requests.post(url = 'http://localhost:80/user', headers=headers, data=data)

print(r.json())
```

Comment: tried but not resolved::{'statusCode': 415, 'code': 'FST_ERR_CTP_INVALID_MEDIA_TYPE', 'error': 'Unsupported Media Type', 'message': 'Unsupported Media Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

Comment: Yes you need to add the headers to the data variable. The request is not being read as application/json

Comment: how can i do that properly. I am kind of learner. Any hint

Comment: I modified my answer, try that

Comment: same error   Unexpected token i in JSON at position 1...

Comment: Are you getting this error on the JS side or Python side?

Comment: python side. Everything is OK with js even i created a another js file and do the same and its works. But when i try to so this stuff with a python script this error pop  up in pycharm console

Comment: is it because of fastify plugin

Answer (score 1):

in the python script:

use `json`

```
r = requests.post(url = 'http://localhost:80/user', headers=headers, json=data)
```

in the node script:

use `.send` method

```
const {first_name, last_name} =req.body;
const fullname={first_name, last_name};
res.send(fullname);
```

Comment: don't know how to thank you.. its works. You just save me. thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

here is the answer to your error:

```
axios.post('url', data, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    }
```